# How to track down what is causing the errors on my site

Tags: c#, asp.net

When i go to several pages on my site I now get this error. 90% of the time my site works and then 10% i get this error message. By just refreshing the page the content will eventually appear. The error appears completely random.

The problem I have is that I don't know how to diagnose the cause of the fault from here. How would I review the stack to work out what is causing this? What would be the best way to track down the cause of this fault?

[image]

Comment: Seems like sometimes a variable doesn't load on time and sometimes it does. When it doesn't load it causes a `NullReferenceException` as you can see from the stack trace. More can be said by looking at your source code

Comment: If you run your app with the debugger, it will allow you to inspect your call stack.

Comment: A good place to start would be to step through your code with the [debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2017).  You should try to figure out exactly what is unexpectedly null, then try to figure out why it's null.  Maybe a dependency call (like to a database) didn't return expected results?  If you are unable to determine what's wrong after using a debugger, try posting your controller code (and anything it calls) and ask a specific question about what you're seeing.

Comment: Given that call stack, are you using session state or the `TempData` dictionary?

Comment: Did you use a `null` key with `TempData` by mistake? Used a custom TempDataProvider?

Comment: Guess you doing work on sessin object out of your HttpContext

Comment: What's confusing to me is that I don't see any of your code in the stack trace. It's all internal to ASP.NET and MVC. Which leads me to think you may have found a bug in the framework. Are you able to create a [MCVE]?

Comment: On some pages ive been storing a list of returned items from a sql database to reduce the load on the sql server. Im trying to recreate the error. At the momen im working on the assumption that a cookie might have expired, meaning the TempData that is linked to it wont be accessible.

Comment: My code doesn't throw any errors. Even pages without any code (just .cshtml view pages) cause the error, that they disappears after a few seconds of refreshing

Comment: @ChristopherVickers which means you are using *Cookies* for temporary data storage? The call stack goes through SessionStateTempDataProvider though. Has the session expired? What do you use for session storage?

Comment: It's the strangest thing. I don't seem to be able to recreate the error. I have code that should redirect the user to another page to log back in if the cookie/session has expired